# How to call API using curl in php

Tags: php, curl, laravel, laravel-4

I have developed some API using laravel and created a virtual host on my local machine.
like abc.xyz.com/api/v1/oauth2/token for getting oauth token. Now I want to test these API
from another local app say abc.com using curl.

I am not getting any response .How can I do this ?Where both apps are in my local machine.

Comment: Maybe show some code, then we can take a look at your code and tell you whats wrong about your code or what a better solution is. And maybe a tip, use `Guzzle`

Comment: I always test first with Postman rest client.

Comment: $requestData = array(
   'client_id' => 'test123',
   'client_secret' => 'bPuD40fvL6eibi11i5iUH9T9jMR89p01',
   'username' => 'abc@example.com',
   'password' => 'somepassword',
   'grant' => 'pass',
  );
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
   CURLOPT_URL => 'http://abc.example.com/api/v1/oauth2/token',
   CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'OAuth Token Grant Request',
   CURLOPT_POST => 1,
   CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $requestData,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
   CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false
   
  ));
  $resp = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curl will give you a lot of trouble to do many things, use Guzzle to consume your API. It's simple, it has it all figured out and it works:

Install

```
composer require "guzzlehttp/guzzle" "~4.0"
```

Create a client:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

Get results:

```
$response = $client->get('http://abc.example.com/api/v1/oauth2/token');

dd($response->getBody());
```

Project: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my question myself. Actually I forgot to add / at the end of URL that why is was not giving any response .

Thanks to All for Help